# C# - Logic to open & read a docx file from a sharepoint site returns "Timeouts are not supported on this stream"

Tags: c#, file, ms-word, openxml-sdk

I've run into a situation where I can't seem to read an MS Word file.  I keep getting the error that the File is corrupt but it's not.
I'm using MS Graph to open the file which is located on my SharePoint site, load the contents as a byte array, convert it to a stream, and then use openxml libraries to read the stream as a Word doc.

**Error Message**

'memoryStream.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type System.InvalidOperationException and the error is "Timeouts are not supported on this stream"

```cs
 using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(documentBytes))
```

**Code to open from Sharepoint**

```cs
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes, "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0");

try
{
    string content = "";
    string x ="";
    foreach (var doc in documentsToRead)
    {
        // Make the API call to read the document content                
        using (var stream = await graphClient.Drives[$"{doc.DriveId}"].Items[$"{doc.ItemId}"].Content.GetAsync())
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            // Read the content as a string
            content = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(content);
            x = xmlConverter.ExtractTextFromWordDocument(bytes);
        }
    }
    return x;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    return ex.Message;
}
```

And then this is the code inside ExractTextFromWordDocument():

```cs
// Method to extract text from Word document using Open XML SDK

public string ExtractTextFromWordDocument(byte[] documentBytes)
{
    string extractedText = "";
    try
    {
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(documentBytes))
        { //set stream position to beginning.
            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            try
            {
                using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(memoryStream, false))
                {
                    var body = wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
                    if (body != null)
                    {
                        extractedText = body.InnerText;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Failed while trying to open as a word doc:{ex.Message}");
            }

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"ExtractTextFromWordDocument failed with: {ex.Message}");
    }

    return extractedText;
}
```

**What I've Tried**

1. Made sure the file isn't corrupted.  I can open the file up in MS Word, no problem. The context is straight text - no embedded objects like pictures etc.
2. as you can see I've added logic to explicitly set the stream position to the start of the stream, in case it matters.
3. I'm using OpenXml version 2.20 in a .net 6.0 project:
   `<PackageReference Include="DocumentFormat.OpenXml" Version="2.20.0" />`
4. I've checked the inner exception to make sure the error isn't actually something else.  And as you can see, I have multiple try/catch combos to make sure I know where the code is really failing.

Any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Reading the byte stream you got from the graph API into a string, to read the string using ASCII encoding as bytes again, to create a new stream from that, seems rather superfluous to me. Apart from inefficiency, using some kind of string encoding like ASCII in the middle provides a good chance to corrupt content. `Stream.Copy` and/or `Stream.ToArray` may help when working with byte streams.

Comment: @thehennyy yeah.  I saw that too, after taking a step back.  Cleaned that up.  But the issue was changing to UTF8 instead of using ASCII.